# $\sum_{i=m+1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} < \frac{2}{m}$

Tags: inequality

I'm about to prove Ciesielski's theorem and I'm stuck at some dumb inequality, which should be pretty obvious but for some reason it isn't... This is the inequality I'm stuck at:

For $n>m\geq N$ it holds that:
$$\sum_{i=m+1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} < \frac{2}{m} \leq \frac{2}{N}$$

Comment: Do you now how to compare the sum with $\int_m^{n} \frac  1 {x^{2}} dx$?

Comment: Well, not exactly, since I would have to integrate with respect to the counting measure. But I see your point, since $$\int_m^n \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{2}{m}$$. How would you specify the connection between the sum and this integral?

Comment: mas2.Drawing.Start integrating from m(<m+1). the integrand, summand, is decreasing, and integrate to n (>(n-1)). The integral is larger than the sum.

Comment: You can get rid of $n$ using that $\sum_{i=m+1}^{n} \frac{1}{i^2}< \sum_{i=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n>m\geq N$, 
$$\sum_{i=m+1}^n\frac 1{i^2}<\sum_{i=m+1}^n \frac1{(i-1)i}$$
$$=\sum_{i =m+1}^n\left(\frac 1{i-1}-\frac 1 i\right)=\frac 1 m-\frac 1 n<\frac 1 m\leq  \frac 1N.$$